# Problem when making the same variable true in different part of the code in React/Js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am new to react and i am making a game. Here i have written

```
{showButton && (
      <div>
        <button className="button_player1" onClick={evt => this.useBaron_id(evt,0,0)} >Player1</button>
        <button className="button_player2" onClick={evt => this.useBaron_id(evt,1,0)}>Player2</button>
        <button className="button_player3" onClick={evt => this.useBaron_id(evt,2,0)}>Player3</button>
        <button className="button_player4" onClick={evt => this.useBaron_id(evt,3,0)}>Player4</button>
      </div>
    )}
```

in order to show and unshow buttons if showbutton is true. However i have used it in different `if` statements

```
{showButton && (
      <div>
        <button className="button_player1" onClick={evt => this.useGuard_id(evt,0,0)} >Player1</button>
        <button className="button_player2" onClick={evt => this.useGuard_id(evt,1,0)}>Player2</button>
        <button className="button_player3" onClick={evt => this.useGuard_id(evt,2,0)}>Player3</button>
        <button className="button_player4" onClick={evt => this.useGuard_id(evt,3,0)}>Player4</button>
      </div>
    )}
```

Now it works but every time if there is both Baron and Guard card, this buttons works for both of them, so i dont if if is goes to `useBaron_id` or `useGuard_id` function. I can write seperately 
`showButton` however i have more than 8 cards so i dont want to write like  `showButton` , `showButton1` and etc. Is there any way to make it easier?
Each time i call this functions for each card has its own

```
useBaron = evt => { var { showButton } = this.state;  this.setState({showButton : true})}

useGuard = evt => { var { guard_select_card } = this.state;  this.setState({guard_select_card : true})}
useGuard_id_card = (evt,id) =>  { 
      var { guard_select_card,id_of_card } = this.state; 
      id_of_card=id 
      this.setState({ id_of_card }) 
      this.setState({showButton : true})
      this.setState({guard_select_card : false})
```

And in my `useGuard_id` and `useBaron_id` and turn them off like 
`this.setState({showButton : false})`

Comment: It depends on how you pass showButton, how your component get that value , Will you please create a demo over stackblitz? that way we can help you to debug the issue

Comment: I dont know how stackblitz work =( And how to upload there, but i can modife the question and more precisely

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/fork/react, try to create working demo with your code here